# Joda: Epoch Time Conversion coming as "1970" date

Tags: android, jodatime

So I have epoch seconds coming to Android app from API like this "1701259436" (unix seconds). And then i used Joda Time in GsonAdapter to convert them to date time like below

```
DateTime(it * 1000L)
```

The date is working fine on all devices except on one device where its converting to following:

> ```
> 20-01-1970 17:34
> ```

The expected date is from 2023 November. Its working fine on all devices, except on one device. The problem is that I have rare access to that device as it is off site at a client Location.

Please help me understand the problem

Comment: I don't think we can really tell you much more than what you already know. My personal gut feeling would be that the problem occurs at a different place and `it` does not contain the value that you think it does. Note that the date you mention is `1701240` in Unix seconds timestamp, which looks suspiciously close to the beginning of your value.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Sorry, this "1701259436" is in seconds, and then i am converting it to milli seconds before giving it to Joda. 
If i convert this on other android devices or using this online service epochConverter.com , its giving the desired date time  30 November 2023 08:52:42. The problem is happening on one device. I checked from the API database, and the time is same there. How is this closed to 1970 you said?